# Show text like Confide android app

Tags: java, android, xml

I need to create text display like the Confide app. What I tried is to use `FlowLayout` but then I'm not able to get the row so that I can hide show row wise. There seems to be various options but kinda confused and not able to think wwat exactly to do... Like break the `TextView` and show in `ListView` but then I don't know how to form lines and create `adapter`.

Kindly help me if anyone knows this thing. I tried to search on Google but nothing fruitful.

At present I'm showing `TextView` using `FlowLayout` and showing hiding each `TextView`.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating custom view like this one, lest call it CustomTextView:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
android:background="#FF0000"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:paddingLeft="10dp"
android:paddingRight="10dp"
android:paddingTop="3dp"
android:paddingBottom="3dp" >

<TextView
android:id="@+id/label"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:visibility="invisible"
android:maxLines="1"
android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

</LinearLayout>
```

java code:

```
public class CustomTextView extends FrameLayout implements View.OnClickListener {

    public CustomTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

    public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }

    public CustomTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init(context);
    }

    private void init(Context context) {
        LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.custom_text_view, this);
        setOnClickListener(this);
        mLabelTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.label);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mLabelTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
    }
}
```

To add this views to your container view try something like this:

```
Display display = ((Activity) getContext()).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
mContainerView.removeAllViewsInLayout();
mContainerView.removeAllViews();
int maxWidth = display.getWidth() - 20;

LinearLayout.LayoutParams params;
LinearLayout newLL = new LinearLayout(getContext());
newLL.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
newLL.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
newLL.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

int widthSoFar = 0;

for (CustomTextView customTextView : CustomTextViewList) {

    LinearLayout LL = new LinearLayout(getContext());
    LL.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    LL.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.BOTTOM);
    LL.setLayoutParams(new ListView.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    customTextView.measure(0, 0);
    params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(customTextView.getMeasuredWidth(), FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    LL.addView(customTextView, params);
    LL.measure(0, 0);
    widthSoFar += customTextView.getMeasuredWidth();
    if (widthSoFar >= maxWidth) {
        mContainerView.addView(newLL);

        newLL = new LinearLayout(getContext());
        newLL.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        newLL.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        newLL.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
        params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LL.getMeasuredWidth(), LL.getMeasuredHeight());
        newLL.addView(LL, params);
        widthSoFar = LL.getMeasuredWidth();
    } else {
        newLL.addView(LL);
    }
}
mContainerView.addView(newLL);
```

Example of CustomTextViewList (to answer your question from comment)

```
ArrayList<CustomTextView> CustomTextViewList = new  ArrayList<CustomTextView>()
CustomTextViewList.add(new CustomTextView(context));
CustomTextViewList.add(new CustomTextView(context));
CustomTextViewList.add(new CustomTextView(context));
```

Comment: its a collection of CustomTextView. You have to cut your message to single word and every word store in separate CustomTextView then add them to CustomTextViewList